# Remove line break HTML

Tags: html

I'm wondering how to remove the line break in HTML. For example this code would have two Hello Worlds on top of each other.  I'm sorry if I'm not good enough at programming to be in this site.

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome you have? If you want them directly underneath each other, use `<br />` instead of `<p>`.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this. How about <p> Hello World Hello World </p>

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You've got a few options:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kN3Bp/).

Or:

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kN3Bp/1/).

If it's the white-space between the bottom of the first `p` and the top of the second `p` that you want to remove:

```
p {
    /*      top  right  bottom  left */
    margin: 0    0      0       0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kN3Bp/3/).

Answer (score 5):

The `<p>` tag is a block-level element, meaning that by default it will try to take the entire width of its container. If you must use a `<p>` tag, you can change its behavior with CSS using "display:inline." Although, the `<span>` tag might work better for what you need, since it is an inline element by default.

W3Schools has a lot of information you may find helpful.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: I think this answer is undervalued. For the beginner web developer (i.e. the college student, such as myself just working on Github Pages), this explains a natural solution to making it an inline element. I was trying to put some text next to a Facebook like button in my footer; this was the solution I needed. Thank you!